# Is there a way to select multiple rows in a react-virtualized table?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

I want to be able to select multiple rows at a time from a react-virtualized table, either with click-and-drag, or holding shift to select from one index to another.
I know there is a **onRowClick** method, and I am currently using it for the single row selection, but it's not enough.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First you can add check box in start of every row to keep tack of selected rows
And then you can select multiple rows at a time by calling below function onClick of checkbox.

```
const checkedData = []

 const selectRows = (obj) => {
        const already = checkedData.some(item => item.id === obj.id)
        if (already) {
            const index = checkedData.findIndex(item => item.id === obj.id)
            checkedData.splice(index, 1)
        } else {
            checkedData.push(obj)
        }
    }
```

In this way you can also pop the particular row from array by clicking on that row again or by unCheck the check bok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was about how to add multiple rows with just one action, by holding shift and clicking on a row below the already selected one.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an answer on a related thread.
I checked in the event from the onRowClick method if the shiftKey was pressed and implemented my own selection. I add the rows from the data to the selectedRows.
'data' comes from props. The code is below, hope it helps.

```
const [previousSelectedRow, setPreviousSelectedRow] = useState();
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState();

const handleRowClick = (info) => {

        let localSelectedRows = [];

        if (info.event.shiftKey && previousSelectedRow) {
            const previousSelectedRowIndex = data.findIndex(rowData => rowData.index = previousSelectedRow.index);
            const currentSelectedRowIndex = data.findIndex(rowData => rowData.index = info.index);
            if (previousSelectedRowIndex < currentSelectedRowIndex) {
                for (let i = previousSelectedRowIndex; i < currentSelectedRowIndex; i++) {
                    localSelectedRows.push(data[i);
                }
            } else {
                for (let i = currentSelectedRowIndex; i < previousSelectedRowIndex; i++) {
                    localSelectedRows.push(data[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            setPreviousSelectedRow(info);
            localSelectedRows.push(info.rowData);
        }
        setSelectedRows(localSelectedRows); 
}
```